# Creation of SecureRandom is slow, even in java 8

Tags: java, spring, random, java-8

I searched on this problem. I got impression, it is resolved in java 8. But suddenly, I started getting this problem in my new VM, based of ubuntu 14.04.

> 2015-07-27 14:56:35.324  INFO 11809 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [167,833] milliseconds.

And java version is

> java -version
>   java version "1.8.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Server is ubuntu 14.04.

Another thing is, i running this java process as spring boot application, which has embedded tomcat running.

Any ideas, what could be wrong? 
I even tried,

> **-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom**  option

Comment: Well, I added using different random, at start of java command, and it worked for me.    **java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar xyz..**

Comment: `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` will effectively make your application **less secure**, if you're using random values for security purposes. Dont do that. Instead, simply use `Random` - thats at least a controlled, tested method of reducing computation time for pseudorandom values. It will be pseudorandom enough for non-government / non-military security levels. Dont try to hack tested libraries - you will only hurt yourself.

Comment: It is at the minimum debatable that for normal client software `/dev/random` is less secure than `/dev/urandom`. See for example https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ also the man page states "The /dev/random interface is considered a legacy interface, and /dev/urandom is preferred and sufficient in all use cases, with the exception of applications which require randomness during early boot time"

Answer (score 18):

Try using the following command while running

> java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar demo.jar

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 18, Spring boot and Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing embedded tomcat with undertow, by pasting the snippet below into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It works for me perfectly. SecureRandom issue is a tomcat issue which you can totally replace with another servlet container.