# Java enterprise application starts very slow on Linux PC with Sun JDK 1.6

Tags: java, linux, jboss

Our Java enterprise application(Spring, Hibernate, JSF, JBoss) usually starts for about 1 minute.
We run our application on Windows(SUN/Oracle JDK 1.6) and on AIX(IBM JDK 1.6).
I tried to run it on Linux(16GB, i5) using Sun JDK 1.6.
But by some reason application starts on Linux too long - from 5 to 30 minutes.
I connected to JVM by jvisualvm and tried to analize threaddumps - there are no any bad locks, sleeps, waits, etc.
I changed JDK to IBM JDK 1.6 and now application start for about 4-5 minutes. But it is too long also.
PC is not overloaded.
JBoss without my application starts fast.

What could be wrong?
How can I find what is wrong with my application or linux or PC?

**UPDATE:**
Server was restarted and this problem disappears.

Comment: You mentioned that you analyzed thread dumps. Did you also try profiling from jvisualvm to see what your application is doing in that time?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen How DNS could influence on my application?

Comment: maybe try to run the application in server/development mode (with key '-server' and without) to exclude if the jvm internal optimization is a bottleneck

Comment: @casablanca Application loads Spring configuration, loads classes. Nothing suspicious. But too long.

Comment: Does it connect to a database - is that database in the same network. Use jstack or kill -3 to generate a thread dump.  Enable spring INFO log and check at where it is stopping.

Comment: @gkamal Yes - it uses database. Application do not stopping. It just working very slow.

Comment: Any idea what part is working slow - if you take multiple thread dumps over a period of time (every 2-3 seconds) can you see if any of the threads are stuck in the same place (usually an IO).  What is the heap memory setting (-Xmx, -Xms) can you try setting -Xmx same as -Xms

Comment: Do you see CPU load or I/O load on the machine while the app starts? Perhaps this machine has a slower disk or a poor disk driver (e.g. no good IDE/SATA driver and using compatibility PIO mode)?

Comment: Failing DNS lookups can cause 30 second delays.

Comment: How can I check that there are failing DNS lookups?

Comment: Use visualvm in the JDK to profile your application and find where the time is spent

Comment: Server was restarted and this problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I've already met simular situtation. Tomcat was began too late (about 3 minutes). I've found problem that OpenJDK is incompatible with powerpc (especially IO operations). So we've changed openJDK with IBMJDK. After that problem was gone. Check your processor type and find compatible jdk.

Comment: I am using IBM JDK too. With this JDK application starts for about 4-7 minutes. It is too log. On slow PC with Windows this application starts for about 1 minute.

Comment: What is your operating system? Can you confirm for using IBM JDK?

Comment: Can you add this JVM parameter –Djava.security.egd= file:/dev/./urandom  and try again? Also you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom for more information.

Comment: I will try it. But there are no any problems with startup time of my application now.