# Jersey Client HTTPS performance issue

Tags: java, https, jersey

I am using a `JUnit` test with `JERSEY Client + HTTPS` to test a `secure web service` running on `Jetty`.  One of my calls to `wr.get( ClientResponse.class)` hangs for 10 seconds after every block of `9-10 requests`.  The equivalent `Apache client` code runs in a few milliseconds.  If I switch `Jetty to HTTP` mode the problem disappears.

I am using `Jersey bundle & client 1.14 and Jetty 6.1.26`

The apache client works

```
@Test
public void testApacheClient() throws Exception
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory = new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory();
  Protocol https = new Protocol( "https", socketFactory, 443 );
  Protocol.registerProtocol( "https", https );

  //Finishes in < 1 second
  for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod( "https://localhost:8443/home" );
    client.executeMethod( getMethod );
    String entity = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    getMethod.releaseConnection();
  }
}
```

The Jersey client hangs

```
@Test
public void testJerseyClient() throws Exception

  HostnameVerifier hv = getHostnameVerifier();
  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
  SSLContext ctx = getSslContext();
  config.getProperties().put( HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES,
      new HTTPSProperties( hv, ctx ) );

  Client jerseyClient = Client.create( config );

  //Finishes in < 1 second
  for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    WebResource wr = jerseyClient.resource( "https://www.google.com" );
    ClientResponse cr = wr.get( ClientResponse.class );
    String entity = cr.getEntity( String.class );
    cr.close();
  }

  /* Pauses for 10 seconds after the 10th request, and subsequently after every 9th request.
     Debugging shows waiting at line 'ClientResponse cr = ...'
   */
  for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    WebResource wr = jerseyClient.resource( "https://localhost:8443/home" );
    ClientResponse cr = wr.get( ClientResponse.class );  //10 second pause after requests 9, 18, 27
    String entity = cr.getEntity( String.class ); //This is triggering the problem
    cr.close();
  }

  //Finishes in < 1 second
  for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    WebResource wr = jerseyClient.resource( "https://localhost:8443/home" );
    ClientResponse cr = wr.get( ClientResponse.class );
    cr.close();
  }
}
```

Retrieving the entity from `ClientResponse` seems to trigger the problem, but only in `HTTPS` mode and running against my web server (not `google, facebook, etc`).  I have run `Jersey ServletContainer and Struts ActionServlet` on `Jetty` and the problem occurs with both.  I've also run the web server on different machines on my `subnet` and unit tested from multiple machines.

Jersey HTTPS classes

```
private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
  HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify( String arg0, SSLSession arg1 ) { return true; }
  };
  return hv;
}

private SSLContext getSslContext() throws Exception {      
  private final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" );
  sslContext.init( null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[0]; }
        public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] certs, String authType ) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] certs, String authType ) {}
      }
    }, new SecureRandom()
  );
  return sslContext;
}
```

Jetty SSL connector.  If I use a SelectChannelConnector and unit test with HTTP the problem goes away.

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
      <Set name="allowRenegotiate">true</Set>
      <Set name="Port">8443</Set>
      <Set name="reuseAddress">true</Set>
      <Set name="Host">mgmt-int</Set>
      <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
      <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
      <Set name="keystore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="/usr/app/web-app"/>/conf/keystore.jetty</Set>
      <Set name="password">OBF:1vaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa111111111v</Set>
      <Set name="keyPassword">OBF:1vaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa111111111v</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: Your handshakeTimeout is far too low at 2000ms. Change it to at least 10-15 seconds.

Comment: I increased the handshakeTimeout to 15000ms and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Can you create a thread dump e.g. with `kill -3 pid` on the client while it hangs to see where this happens?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are these running on?

Just a guess, but it could be related to a slow `/dev/random` implementation (via `SecureRandom`).

Related discussion here:

[How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

Since I can't always control JVM parameters in a web app, I've been using this as a workaround:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("java.security.egd", "file:///dev/urandom");
}
```

Don't know if that's strictly speaking recommended (but it solves the problem for me).

Comment: I've run Jetty on Linux 3.0.0-12-generic and 2.6.32.49.  I added the static block to a Java class that gets loaded with Jetty and it didn't help.  The Apache HTTPS client works fine with my Jetty server, and the Jersey Client works fine with https google.  It's only when the Jersey Client runs against my Jetty server does the problem crop up.

Answer (score 0):

Trying modifying your trustManager implementation slightly:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Trust always
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Trust always
            }
        }
    };
```

Also, don't forget to call HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSocketFactory at the end of your getSSLContext() method:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I ended up switching to the Apache client which works fine for me.