# Does the SHA1PRNG algorithm for SecureRandom use /dev/random for entropy?

Tags: java, linux, cryptography

I tried looking for this in the javadocs and online but couldn't find a definitive answer. The answer by Dan Dyer in

[How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

Seems to suggest SHA1PRNG does not use any system resources for entropy. Is this correct?

Comment: The actual implementation is proprietary, sort of. And then of course there are different versions of Java. But at least some versions of Java do use /dev/random. I think that in general, for relatively recent java versions will use /dev/random on systems that have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the default Oracle implementation it uses system resources, unless you seed it before calling `nextBytes()`. From the Sun/Oracle documentation of `SecureRandom`:

> The SecureRandom implementation attempts to completely randomize the internal state of the generator itself unless the caller follows the call to a getInstance method with a call to the setSeed method:
>
> ```
>  SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
>  random.setSeed(seed);
> ```

Comment: Note that this is pretty useless unless the output is precisely specified, as the output may differ on specific providers, even for an algorithm under the same name.