# OpenPgp encryption using Bouncycastle very slow on Unix

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am sign and encrypt a text file of 12 GB using (bcpg-jdk16-145.jar , bcprov-jdk16-145.jar) jar files. File will be encrypted and signed approximately 18 minutes in Windows Vista , jdk 1.6. But when I try to encrypt it on LINUX/UNIX system process will become very slow I takes 1 to 1:30 hours. Kindly suggest.

Code for signing file is as below :

```
private static void signFile(String fileName, InputStream keyIn,
        OutputStream out, char[] pass, boolean armor, int bufferSize)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, PGPException, SignatureException {
    if (armor) {
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
    }
    PGPSecretKey pgpSec = readSecretKey(keyIn);
    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.extractPrivateKey(pass, "BC");
    PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(pgpSec
            .getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1, "BC");
    sGen.initSign(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);
    Iterator it = pgpSec.getPublicKey().getUserIDs();
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
        spGen.setSignerUserID(false, (String) it.next());
        sGen.setHashedSubpackets(spGen.generate());
    }
    PGPCompressedDataGenerator cGen = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
            PGPCompressedData.ZLIB);
    BCPGOutputStream bOut = new BCPGOutputStream(cGen.open(out));
    sGen.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(bOut);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    PGPLiteralDataGenerator lGen = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
    OutputStream lOut = lGen.open(bOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, file);
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
    while (fIn.read(byteArray) >= 0) {
        lOut.write(byteArray);
        sGen.update(byteArray);
    }
    lGen.close();

    sGen.generate().encode(bOut);

    cGen.close();

    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Please post the -jmx etc. flags / settings you are using. Are both systems equal in IO/CPU/memory performance?

Comment: both machines having default VM settings. Buffer size which i was going to pass is 2000 bytes. When I increased buffer size performance is even down of Windows 7 system

Comment: And what about the performance of the systems per se? Have you run a performance test in order to compare both systems (or better boot first windows than linux on the same machine)?

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `fIn.read(byteArray)`. Disregarding the speed issue, with the very high probability the result of that code is complete garbage because the call to `fIn.read(byteArray)` is not guaranteed to read exactly `byteArray.length` bytes, but you pass the whole array to the `lOut.write()` and `sGen.update()`.

Comment: Beside the comments from @OlegEstekhin try to use a BufferedInputStream instead of FileInputStream.

Comment: I have tried BufferedInputStream as well but no gain

Comment: I'm going to guess that the Windows machine has an SSD but the Linux machine has an HDD. Have you done what @ooxi suggested?

Answer (score 7):

This is an educated guess, maybe you're having a problem with /dev/random?

PGP is going to use a secure hash, which in Java will probably rely on SecureRandom.  The default source for SecureRandom in Linux (but not Windows) is /dev/random.

The problem is that SecureRandom will block waiting for /dev/random to gather more entropy if it currently can't satisfy the number of bits requested.

Try installing a utility called "haveged" (apt-get install or whatever).  It will gather more entropy for your linux system and prevent this behavior.

Comment: Can you please recommend some open source API which will not use /dev/random

Comment: With SecureRandom you can set a provider and seed (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923247/does-the-sha1prng-algorithm-for-securerandom-use-dev-random-for-entropy).  However, any serious cryptographic library will *not* do that as it is not a reliable way to generate randomness.  Installing haveged is your simplest option.

Comment: Thank you spudone. Unfortunately haveged does not support Sun sparc architecture. Is there any other option

Comment: There may be a way to configure BouncyCastle to use /dev/urandom but I'm not very familiar with it.  Another option is rngd, which can feed /dev/random with data from a hardware device.  If you don't have such a hardware device you could try abusing it to use urandom (something like "rngd -r /dev/urandom").  This will increase your entropy in /dev/random even though it's now a pseudoRNG.