# Selenium Server doesn't bind to socket after being killed with SIGTERM

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jetty

After being killed once, selenium server hangs on all further startups without even trying to acquire the server port.

Rebooting fixes the problem. Running as a different user makes selenium start up again as well, but after *that* process gets killed it won't work no more.

This is on Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (debian squeeze) in a VirtualBox VM. Looking at a log of the system calls when it's [working](https://gist.github.com/4389650) and [when it's not](https://gist.github.com/4389655), some component seems to lock up before the socket is even bound. The [selenium log](https://gist.github.com/4389679) isn't of much help.

The output doesn't give any indication either:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
Dec 27, 2012 5:41:35 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
17:41:35.703 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.0-b16
17:41:35.704 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 amd64
17:41:35.737 INFO - v2.28.0, with Core v2.28.0. Built from revision 18309
17:41:35.867 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
17:41:35.868 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
17:41:35.868 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
17:41:35.869 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
17:41:35.869 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a Java problem; its RNG needlessly reads from `/dev/random`. On a VM, the random pool is limited and often exhausted after one or two runs. For some reason, a part of the selenium/Jetty startup asks for the problematic RNG. To fix the problem, [advise Java to use `/dev/urandom` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/35070):

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
     -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

works fine.

Comment: I believe the problem relates to how /dev/random is seeded/populated. It takes input from keyboard/mouse and possibly network, and drives the random number generation from this. If there's no such input (and for a VM particularly you can understand the keyboard/mouse issue) then /dev/random will hang waiting for more input

Comment: Eh, known but often overlooked problem! Good find... And yes, it is strange indeed that specifying `/dev/urandom` as a value to `java.security.egd` will not work... This is a bug, whatever Oracle/Sun may say.

Comment: @BrianAgnew it is not quite so. While, theoretically, your explanation is correct, the program will behave exactly the same if you specify `/dev/urandom`. For some obscure reason, as of yet unexplained, Sun/Oracle aliased that to `/dev/random`, and as a result the same bug would appear.

Comment: thanks for this @phihag, would never have figured that out without this answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of dark magic you used to find this (combo-ed with the /dev/urandom alias). This is entirely crazy. Would really like to know how you found this (I'm far from a Java expert, was just trying to run selenium with my E2E tests)

Comment: And **thank you**, this problem was insane, I would have never solved it without you

Comment: I looked very closely at the strace logs (with timing if memory serves) and saw that the reads were blocking. After that, I knew where the problem was and had to find out how to reconfigure Java.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks, I might apply this strategy in the future!