# Generating UUID takes a long time

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

When my application first sets up a `UserTransaction` for `Hibernate`, it takes ten minutes to do so. I have gone through the stack and it hangs on a `UUID.generateRandom()`.

Comment: can you provide some code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: which OS/arch are you running?

Comment: Could it be that you face timeout issues related to  TCP/IP? There are four different basic types of UUIDs: time-based, DCE security, name-based, and randomly generated UUIDs. DCE is TCP/IP related.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom

Comment: `/dev/random` may be slow, but we're talking *milliseconds* slow, not *minutes*.

Comment: It is internal Hibernate. The system is Windows and the UUID is randomly generated. The programme is running as a service. Oddly, it depends on the user that is used for running the service. The standard system user works fine, but i need to use a user from the workgroup (for sharing reasons). Then it takes 10-15 min.

Comment: The problem is caused when we transferred from Hibernate 3.x to 4.x. The followig code has been added `serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry()`. The system hangs on this (The slow call `UUID.randomUUID()` is called in there)