# java slow : entropy related issue

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, weblogic

I am running into an issue where java is slow when used over SSL. The solution is to add

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

to java at the command line. Since I have multiple JVM's, I dont want to modify every single JVM to contain this string and hence would like to add it to the file

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Now, the java.security file already contains

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

Two questions on this :

1. Why and how is "/dev/urandom" different from "/dev/./urandom". Why doesnt java accept "/dev/urandom"
2. For the JVM's that I have running, how can I tell whether they are using the correct urandmon device (vs random)

Comment: `/dev/./urandom` and `/dev/urandom` are the same path, there's no difference.

Comment: There should not be, but apparently there is

Comment: hum. weird. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/635608

Comment: Yup, just arrived at the same conclusion ! Bug 6202721 explains it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a hack introduced into the JVM back in 1.3 or 1.4 days.

- [JDK-4705093 : Use /dev/urandom rather than /dev/random if it exists.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4705093)
- [JDK-6202721 : SHA1PRNG reads from /dev/random even if /dev/urandom selected](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6202721)

The basic issue is that in the native JVM code they hardcoded `/dev/urandom` to actually use `/dev/random` to attempt to ensure sufficient entropy.  Since `/dev/urandom` is supposed to be guaranteed not to block, this has the unintended consequence of blocking if not enough entropy is available.

The hardcoding looks specifically for the string `/dev/urandom`, so providing something that resolves to the same thing but doesn't match that causes the desired behavior.  If you code `/dev/./urandom` you bypass the hardcoded aliasing and get to the intended `urandom` entropy source.

Comment: this reminds me that unix uses the dot method for recursive folder search. technically it could look like this: file:/dev/...

Answer (score 4):

Using /dev/urandom (non blocking) is fine for most cases. Personally I would make sure to have some HW random number generator configured to be positive to have enough entropy (see below).

If you have to use /dev/random (blocking) and you cannot block then you should make sure to always have enough entropy. A solution to this is to configure a HW random number generator.

Assuming your on Linux you can check the available entropy with:

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`

If you are on a machine that has a hw random number generator you most probably want to install rngd. You can check if your cpu has one by issuing the command:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Look for flags called *rand*. You can also check if the file /dev/hwrng is present. You might have/want to load the corresponding module:

`ls /lib/modules/*/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random`

For me this is:

`sudo modprobe tpm-rng`

To make it permanent:

`echo tpm-rng | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

If you happen to be on Ubuntu/Debian just install the package rng-tools.

`sudo aptitude install rng-tools`

If you check your entropy before and after installing rng-tools you should see a significant increase.

The following command should show you available entropy sources:

`sudo rngd -f -r /dev/hwrng -v`

Note that if you need better security you want to mix multiple entropy sources. Not sure rng-tools supports this.