# Why loading personal keystore takes so much time?

Tags: java, security, keystore

I use the code below to get certificate from personal keystore in java but the statement 
ksp.load(null,null) takes 14 seconds to execute which I am not able to figure out why and how I can reduce it. I am able to sign the pdf document with the certificate but the whole process takes 1 minute which I wanted to be 1 sec.

```
SunMSCAPI SunProvider=new SunMSCAPI();
Security.addProvider(SunProvider);
KeyStore ksp = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ksp.load(null,null);
java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain = ksp.getCertificateChain(certName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it is the SecureRandom seeding. Cyrpto requires strong random number generation. One of the techniques for this is to run an algorithm for a long time, producing an unpredictable number at the end.  Solutions might be:

- find a way to do this "ahead of time", and that it only happens once.
- find a crypto implementation / JVM which has a different faster implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not get your point of finding a crypto implementation/JVM which has a different faster implementation. How can I do that.

Comment: I dont have the exact answer, and maybe SecureRandom isn't even your problem. (But i have experienced this problem before myself.)  Try google searches for "SecureRandom slow" and see what you find. I found this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom

Comment: I ended up writing windows service for it.