# Tools available to investigate Tomcat startup time

Tags: java, tomcat, jvisualvm, thread-dump, embedded-tomcat-8

I am in reference to [Tomcat's HowTo improve startup time](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#General).

Can someone please provide informed advice as to how to determine where Tomcat spends time starting up?

Should I use `jvisualvm`, `jstack`?

Are thread dumps the only way to find out more information as to what Tomcat is actually doing whilst starting up?

Comment: just a comment: I had serious perofrmance issue with Tomcat 8 startup. For me, adding the cli arg  
 `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` solved it. [details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added that already. It does help but I still need to investigate further. :-)

Comment: Have you tried a profiler like YourKit ?

Comment: Thanks Wim. I have jvisualvm setup on my laptop but I am not sure which classes to profile... Do you know which of the Tomcat classes I should profile?

Comment: No sorry. I never used YourKit for tomcat performance improvements, only for checking my own code.