# weblogic.Deployer gets slow when running multiple times

Tags: java, performance, deployment, weblogic, slowdown

I deploy some EAR to a remote weblogic server with

`java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://weblogic:7001/ -username weblogic -password weblogic1 -deploy /tmp/package.ear -remote`

But when I run this command multiple times, it's getting really slow to deploy (like 10-15 minutes to deploy a small EAR/WAR).

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to add the parameter `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` to the java command. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/2179668) and [this post](http://purvishpurohit.blogspot.be/2013/02/mystery-of-slow-oracle-weblogic-j2ee.html) for more details.

The complete command becomes

`java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./dev/urandom weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://weblogic:7001/ -username weblogic -password weblogic1 -deploy /tmp/package.ear -remote`