# Mule ESB 3.8/JDK 8 - Verbose Debugging/Tracing of timings for Flow execution

Tags: performance, mule, mule-component

On Mule 3.8 Standalone Runtime with Java 8, we are testing a Scatter Gather flow mainly with outbound HTTP calls.

When running concurrent calls by a load test script, some flows have an unexplainable 1 minute wait; we can't see any traces in logs (brought down to Debug) or any other cause in the ESB runtime. HTTP services themselves are fine - no latency from services end whatsoever (monitored separately).

Is there some sort of a checklist for looking into Mule configuration parameters when we run such a test? Any other verbose diagnostic flags we can turn on to see extended trace info?

Comment: Do you have enough threads for handling the load you are using?

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't a thread contention issue.


When we analyzed stack traces extracted in periodic intervals, we identified a java.util.SecureRandom.generateSeed() stack recurring consistently but in RUNNING state; turns out that Secure Random on Linux systems might be really slow - as discussed in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom). 


Resorting to a slightly less secure /dev/urandom via -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom solved our wait issue.