# Slow JRuby performance when running Ruby scripts from Java

Tags: java, jruby

I'm using JRuby to run some Ruby scripts from Java and collect the results. Everything works fine, but performance is unacceptably slow - while executing `script.rb` from terminal takes about 0.3 seconds, executing it via JRuby from Java takes over 10 seconds. The code I'm using is:

```
ScriptingContainer jruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalContextScope.THREADSAFE);
String script = readScript("script.rb");
Object receiver = jruby.runScriptlet(script);   // takes ~10 seconds
Map<String, String> executionResult = (Map<String, String>) jruby.callMethod(receiver, ...);
```

The bottleneck is the `runScriptlet()` method, which takes 8-10 seconds on an otherwise normally performant Linux machine. I'm using JRuby 9.1.6.0 with Java 8 (openjdk 1.8).

Am I doing something wrong - perhaps missing some essential settings - or is this just how slow JRuby really is? Has anybody else encountered this?

Comment: Can you post the scripts code? That might be the problem - JRuby is *apparently* faster than the C compiler

Comment: @LukeMelaia I'm using the script that is mostly the same as the one in the example [here](https://github.com/WinRb/WinRM). Even if the script is a single-line "puts 'Hi!'", the `runScriptlet` takes ~5 seconds.

Comment: How fast does the script run if you run it a second time?  Likely the performance hit is in reading and processing everything necessary to actually run the script, so if there's a way, only do that once and run the script over and over.

Comment: @AndrewHenle subsequent calls to `runScriptlet` are faster, but still rather slow (i.e. multiple seconds). However, this is not good enough: I need the initial delay to be must shorter.

Comment: there must be smt blocking in that case -> usual candidate is low entropy on the system. try an advice from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/454312) to confirm.

Comment: @kares I ran the program with the `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` parameter, without any noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: sorry, in that case its all about finding out the bottlenecks using JVM tools