# How to generate all possible 64 bit random values in java?

Tags: java, random, generator, long-integer, secure-random

Does Java `SecureRandom.nextLong()` return all possible values given it inherits from `Random` which uses only 48 bits? If not, can I still do it in Java maybe by modifying the Random class and how to do it? I just want to use an all random long number generator where all possible long values can be returned, if possible.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question's wording. I'm guessing you don't want to generate all possible Long values. I'm guessing that you want a random number from the set of all possible Long values?

Comment: If you truly want a random number (not based on discrete mathematics) you should visit some online sites. For example:
[random.org](https://www.random.org/)

Comment: @zlakad unless you want it cryptographically secure in which case you definitely *don't* want to get random data from another source.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes, I see what you mean. I wrote an algorithm in assembler for Z80 processor for generations of random bites back in 1982-3. God, I forgot everything about it!

Comment: Yes, from the set of all possible long values and not necessary all long values.

Comment: @zlakad web sites could record your random numbers or be hacked to record them. Why would any on bother? When you have a private keys worth ~$1 bn https://etherscan.io/accounts recording sources of random data becomes interesting to some.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Agreed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While SecureRandom inherits from Random, it doesn't use the same maths or have the same limitation. It will produce all possible 64-bit values eventually.

> This class provides a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG).

This class delegates to one of many possible implementations. You can select one by calling `SecureRandom.getInstance(algorithm)`

Note: some implementations use entropy in your computer to make the results random, rather than purely pseudo random.

> this uses s 48 bit algorighm

SecureRandom doesn't use any of the methods of it's parent e.g.

```
/**
 * The provider implementation.
 */
private SecureRandomSpi secureRandomSpi = null;

public void nextBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    secureRandomSpi.engineNextBytes(bytes);
}
```

This method delegates to a completely different implementation.

Related link [How to solve slow Java `SecureRandom`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-slow-java-securerandom) due to using /dev/random

Comment: I hope that this is true

Comment: upvoted, as I share the understanding of @PeterLawrey

Comment: @EngineerDollery Unfortunately, `Random` is not an interface but is widely used, so the designers decided to extend Random, but replace it with a completely different implementation, but since it extends Random it can be used as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Ok, downvote removed. I should be more weary of disagreeing with you ;)