# Generate random UUID non blocking

Tags: java, reactive-programming, uuid, spring-webflux, project-reactor

By using Blockhound *io.projectreactor.tools blockhound-junit-platform* i found out that UUID.randomUUID is a blocking call which is a problem for us since we are using Spring boot Webflux version 2.2.2.RELEASE

Is there any other way to get a random uuid in a non blocking way or is there any other java library recommended for non blocking generation of randomized strings.

Stack trace from blockhound:

```
java.lang.Error: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$new$0(BlockHound.java:196) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain][ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
    at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$new$0(BlockHound.java:196) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$install$6(BlockHound.java:318) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.blockhound.BlockHoundRuntime.checkBlocking(BlockHoundRuntime.java:46) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:526) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:545) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:741) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:150) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Is this really a problem? Getting enough random bytes from the OS random number source used to be a problem on older Linux versions, but it should be pretty fast now. And maybe that this only happens the first time you generate a UUID?

Comment: See this thread for a discussion about why the default entropy source can be slow and how to select a different one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-deal-with-a-slow-securerandom-generator

Comment: If you do run into slowness and don't want to block your "reactive" thread, you could generate all UUID on a dedicated worker pool, same as you would do with other blocking things. But it does seem overkill.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Blocking calls should not be used in reactive program even though they are fast. I agree creating a separate thread pool for generating the uuid seems overkill. No other library available for generating random id's that is recommended to use for reactive applications?

Comment: There is no problem with this (unless seeding the SecureRandom is really slow). Class-loading is blocking as well. Don't fall into the premature "optimisation" trap and focus on demonstrable performance issues.

Comment: my question is, is it a problem that the uuid random is blocking? have you measured it to be a problem?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a workaround on this blocking call, regardless of how small is the impact?

Comment: If there's no way to say to blockhound that this is not an error I think the error is that one should disable the entire blockhound checks to use the UUID, was any solution found for this?

Comment: You should check on the first comment about why the call is taking so much time. But in general to wrap a synchronous blocking call you go Mono.fromCallable(UUID::randomUUID).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())

Comment: +1 to suggestion by @JEY - this is the right fix for an operation like this that does have IO and is blocking even if expected to be quick.

Answer (score 3):

This is a list of three examples on how to use [uuid-creator](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator) to reduce thread contention on Linux.

An additional example uses [ulid-creator](https://github.com/f4b6a3/ulid-creator) to generate [Monotonic ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec) and then turn them into RFC-4122 UUID (standard). Monotonic ULID generation is *very fast*.

The benchmark code is available on a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/fabiolimace/e6b773ccce864bc35e4c1797131f2f27).

#### Example 1: using `UuidCreator` and `SHA1PRNG`

How to setup the `SHA1PRNG` algorithm to be used by `UuidCreator`:

```bash
# Append to /etc/environment or ~/.profile
# Use the the algorithm SHA1PRNG for SecureRandom
export UUIDCREATOR_SECURERANDOM="SHA1PRNG"
```

```java
// generate a random-based UUID
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getRandomBased();
```

`UuidCreator` uses a fixed pool of `SecureRandom`. The variable `UUIDCREATOR_SECURERANDOM` tells `UuidCreator` to use another `SecureRandom` algorithm, instead of `NativePRNG` on Linux. `UuidCreator` along with `SHA1PRNG` algorithm generates UUIDs with less thread contention (less-blocking) than `UUID.randomUUID()`.

See the benchmark using 4 threads:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt      Score     Error   Units
----------------------------------------------------------------------
UUID.randomUUID()             thrpt    5   1423,060 ±  30,125  ops/ms
UuidCreator.getRandomBased()  thrpt    5  10616,016 ± 281,486  ops/ms
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Example 2: using `ThreadLocalRandom`

How to implement a UUID generator using `ThreadLocalRandom`:

```java
public class UuidGenerator {

    private static final RandomBasedFactory UUID_FACTORY;

    static {
        UUID_FACTORY = new RandomBasedFactory((int length) -> {
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(bytes);
            return bytes;
        });
    }

    public static UUID generate() {
        return UUID_FACTORY.create();
    }
}
```

`ThreadLocalRandom` is a fast (and unsafe) random generator without thread contention (non-blocking).

See the benchmark using 4 threads:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt      Score      Error   Units
----------------------------------------------------------------------
UUID.randomUUID()            thrpt    5   1423,060 ±   30,125  ops/ms
UuidGenerator.generate()     thrpt    5  85390,979 ± 1564,589  ops/ms
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Example 3: using `RandomBasedFactory[]` and `SHA1PRNG`

How to implement a UUID generator using ana array of `RandomBasedFactory` and `SHA1PRNG` algorithm:

```java
    public static class UuidGenerator {

        private static final int SIZE = 8; // you choose
        private static final RandomBasedFactory[] FACTORIES;

        static {
            FACTORIES = new RandomBasedFactory[SIZE];
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < FACTORIES.length; i++) {
                    // SHA1PRNG or DRBG can be used to reduce thread contention.
                    SecureRandom argument = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                    FACTORIES[i] = new RandomBasedFactory(argument);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // oops!
            }
        }

        public static UUID generate() {
            // calculate the factory index given the current thread ID
            final int index = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId() % SIZE;
            return FACTORIES[index].create();
        }
    }
```

An array of `RandomBasedFactory` with and `SHA1PRNG` algorithm can generate UUIDs with less thread contention (less-blocking).

See the benchmark using 4 threads:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt      Score      Error   Units
----------------------------------------------------------------------
UUID.randomUUID()            thrpt    5   1423,060 ±   30,125  ops/ms
UuidGenerator.generate()     thrpt    5  10048,747 ±  195,209  ops/ms
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Example 4: using `UlidCreator` and `Monotonic ULIDs`

How to use [ulid-creator](https://github.com/f4b6a3/ulid-creator) to generate RFC-4122 UUIDs from [Monotonic ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec):

```java
// create a Monotonic ULID and convert it to RFC-4122 UUID v4
UUID uuid = UlidCreator.getMonotonicUlid().toRfc4122().toUuid();
```

See the benchmark using 4 threads:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt     Score      Error   Units
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
UUID.randomUUID()              thrpt    5  1423,060 ±   30,125  ops/ms
UlidCreator.getMonotonicUlid() thrpt    5  7391,917 ±  871,799  ops/ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**: added the 4th example that uses Monotonic ULID.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the main contributor of `uuid-creator`.

Answer (score 3):

There [is a way](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/customization.md#dis-allowing-blocking-calls-inside-methods) to tell BlockHound to ignore `UUID.randomUUID()`.

And there is a good reason to do so.
Blockhound blames UUID.randomUUID() to use a file read operation, because file operations contain the risk to transfer some data to/from a disk.

/dev/random and /dev/urandom are not of that kind. The data is coming from the memory directly.

Since Java 8, Java uses /dev/urandom, which guarantees on top of /dev/random, that it won't block even if the entropy pool runs low. Which means, that in the whole stack down to the kernel, the CPU has always work to do.

Not using /dev/urandom makes solutions cryptographically weak. You could directly fallback to time-based UUIDs.
Pushing it to other Threads as suggested by @downvoteit just adds overhead. The work needs to be done anyway to handle the request.

The performance-measurements by @fabiolimace indicate, that even using a cryptographically questionable solution and only generating UUIDs, you gain the factor 10 at its best. In reality, when UUID generation is not your bottleneck, you probably won't even notice the difference in terms of throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution has been suggested by JEY (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976843/jey) in the comments.

I am just sharing my BlockHound tested code for `UUID` and `SecureRandom`.

For `UUID`:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> UUID.randomUUID().toString())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

And another commonly used apparently blocking, `SecureRandom`:

```java
private final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

Mono.fromCallable(() -> random.nextInt(1_000))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

Tested on:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 2.7.6
- BlockHound 1.0.7.RELEASE (no modifications)