# JPaseto token creation takes 2min

Tags: paseto

I have tried to run
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-jpaseto-example
which works fine but
the code for creating a token takes 2min+ and some runs have been 7min

I have also followed the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOyG68jvthM
which also has that problem with token creation.
this code is usually around the 2min mark

Link to core lib: https://github.com/paseto-toolkit/jpaseto

From my understanding paseto will create a token you give the user after they login. Which can be used to identify the user. But waiting 2min+ seems a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and in my case the problem was due to the fact that JPaseto uses `SecureRandom`. `SecureRandom` get it's randomness from `/dev/random` which can and will block if not enough entropy is available.

You can use tools like [haveged](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged) to generate additional entropy on your system.

The installation should be simple enough (Ubuntu/Debian)

```
apt-get install haveged
update-rc.d haveged defaults
service haveged start
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-deal-with-a-slow-securerandom-generator) may also provide some different solutions.